# How to automatically load function in PHP

Tags: php, autoload

I use this code to load classes

```
 function __autoload($className)
 {
      $files = dirname(__FILE__).'/public/class/'.$className.'.php';

      if(file_exists($files))
      {
           include_once($files);
      }
 }
```

does anyone know how to retrieve the function automatically, too? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoloader function registered [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) can be used to load classes, but **not** functions. Wrap your functions in class or classes to utilize autoloading, i.e.

```
class Utils {
  static function foo() {
    ..
  }
}
```

then call it static way:

```
Utils::foo();
```

and you can have it autoloaded when needed. See more infromation on [autoloading in PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: Too do not understand what you mean, an example? Thank you very much

Comment: Just add `static` keyword to function declaration as in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can automatically load **classes** using the autoload feature, but **no**, you can't do the same for **functions**.